# Creating Multiple GCP Storage Buckets

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a web application, in which users are allowed to upload files and other documents.  A concern to me is making sure these uploaded documents are encrypted at all times.  I have implemented SSL as an initial security measure, but once that document/file arrives within the bucket, how can I make sure the files are encrypted there?  I have multiple users who log into use my service and each of them have their own access as to upload docs, think of it like a mini-dropbox service.  Its just there to upload some files for storage.  Is the correct way to use Google Cloud Storage to create one bucket per client or can I just dump everything in one bucket?  I am new to GCP here, so trying to figure all this out, so any help and guidance would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance for your help.  - AJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage [encrypts all the uploaded data](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption) on server side before the data is written to disk and stored. Your data is safe here.

However, if you want to add even more security to them or you manage users' sensitive data, you can also use:

- [Customer-supplied encryption keys](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-supplied-keys) where you can create and manage your own encryption keys for server-side encryption, which act as an additional encryption layer on top of the standard Cloud Storage encryption.
- [Customer-managed encryption keys](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-managed-keys) where you generate and manage your encryption keys using Cloud Key Management Service, which act as an additional encryption layer on top of the standard Cloud Storage encryption.

Or maybe you want to take a look at the [Client-side encryption option](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/client-side-keys): which is encryption that occurs before data is sent to Cloud Storage. Such data arrives at Cloud Storage already encrypted but also undergoes server-side encryption.

As you can see, there are plenty options to secure data here, additional to the default one.

Yes, it is OK to use a single Bucket for all the application because:

1. You are only charged by the amount of [stored Data](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#storage-pricing), [Network](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-pricing) and [Operations performed](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing).

There are also charges for [Retrieving Data](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#archival-pricing). This only applies for Archival storage buckets, such as Coldline, Nearline or Archive. I highly recommend you to take a look at the [Stroage classes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes) to make sure you have chosen the right one.

2. Google Cloud Storage offers a >99% of availability for any Bucket Class as part of their [Service Level Agreement](https://cloud.google.com/storage/sla) so it is quite difficult for your application to see interruptions from this service (but not impossible).

However, it is possible to experience some latency if your bucket is on North America and your users are, let's say in Asia or Europe (not too much to worry here, but these milliseconds could be key for customer experience).

3. Google Cloud Storage buckets don't have a storage limit but you also might want to make sure you are following the [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices), such as using [valid bucket names](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-buckets), using [valid objects (file) names](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-objects) and making sure you are [not uploading files of 5TB or more](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#objects). These could be validations that you can make from your app's side to avoid any "surprise".

After that, I think you are OK. If your service does not behave as expected, please reach out the [GCP support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support) team via your Cloud Console.